# Рекурсивное добавление значений в массив

Tags: php

Необходимо добавить значение счетчика в каждый массив. Исходный массив имеет следующий вид:

```
$arryGroup = array(
                            0=>array(
                                    0=>array(
                                            0=>'zapic_auc_sluga'
                                    ),
                                    1=>array(
                                            0=>array(
                                                    0=>'aukcion'
                                            ),
                                            1=>array(
                                                    0=>'book_firma',
                                                    1=>'predmet'
                                            )
                                    )
                            ),
                            1=>array(
                                0=>'poluchenie',
                                1=>'firma',
                                2=>'prodavec',
                                3=>'rel_zapis'),
                            2=>array(
                                0=>'poluchenie',
                                1=>'firma',
                                2=>'prodavec',
                                3=>'rel_zapis'
                            ));
```

И и чтобы массив преобразовывался в следующий вид. Просто мне в алгоритме необходимо иметь идентификаторы дочерних массивов:

```
$arryGroup = array(
                            0=>array(
                                    0=>array(
                                            0=>'zapic_auc_sluga',
                                            1=>1
                                    ),
                                    1=>array(
                                            0=>array(
                                                    0=>'aukcion',
                                                    1=>3
                                            ),
                                            1=>array(
                                                    0=>'book_firma',
                                                    1=>'predmet',
                                                    2=>4
                                            ),
                                            2=>2
                                    ),
                                    2=>0
                            ),
                            1=>array(
                                0=>'poluchenie',
                                1=>'firma',
                                2=>'prodavec',
                                3=>'rel_zapis',
                                4=>5),
                            2=>array(
                                0=>'poluchenie',
                                1=>'firma',
                                2=>'prodavec',
                                3=>'rel_zapis',
                                4=>6
                            ),
                            5=>7);
```

Написал следующую рекурсивную функцию:

```
function recursive($array, $level = 0){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            array_push($value,$level);
            recursive($value, $level + 1);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

И ее вызов:

```
$recursive = recursive($GlobalTable);
```

Но она не работает должным образом. Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, а то 2 день мучаюсь нифига не получается.

Comment: дак вы уровень рекурсии измеряете, а не номера расставляете.

Comment: Просто я вызываю рекурсивно функцию увеличивая счетчик и добавляя это значение в массив, но пока не получается грамотно добавлять значения

Comment: в результирующем массиве в конце `5 => 7` должно быть видимо `3 => 7` ?

Comment: Да, так и должно быть, описался прошу прощения:)

Comment: вы в следующий раз указывайте в вопросе, что вам не важен порядок нумерации.

Comment: Ну просто мне нужна иерархия вложенных массивов.
Я вот не понял вашего сообщения 
"заметьте, нумерация узлов в вашем решении не соответствует той, что требуется в вопросе."(с)
Как лучше можно это организовать тогда (учитывая порядок нумерации)?

Comment: Я про то, что код в моем ответе расставляет номера в точности как у вас в вопросе приведено. Код в соседнем ответе расставляет номера просто по-порядку. Если вам конкретные номера не нужны (а чтобы каждый вложенный массив просто получил уникальный номер), то надо просто это указывать в вопросе. В вашем же примере нумерации  у вас сначала добавляется номер, потом уходит в рекурсию,  исключая самый верхний узел,  где поведение противоположное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведенном вами коде вы в переменной `$level` считаете уровень рекурсии. В таком случае в результате все элементы на одном уровне имеют одно и тоже добавленное значение. Вам же надо каждый раз встречая массив увеличивать общий счетчик.
В целом из за способа обхода (вершина имеет последний номер), текущий уровень рекурсии тоже знать необходимо. Для простоты можете представить себе этот вложенный массив как дерево. Вы обходите узлы сверху-внизу слева направо. Посещая каждый узел необходимо увеличивать счетчик узлов и добавлять его в массив.

```
$num = 0;

function processArray(&$data, &$num, $level){
    if($level){
       $data[] = $num++;
    }
    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            processArray($data[$k], $num, $level+1);
        }
    }
    if(!$level){
        $data[] = $num;
    }
}

processArray($arrayGroup, $num, 0);
print_r($arrayGroup);
```

Если мы в данном коде уберем условия, связанные с `$level` то на самом верхнем уровне массива у нас будет значение `0`, а с данным условием значение будет соответствовать `7`. Конечно, можно реализовать этот нюанс обхода и другим способом, начать счет с -1, а после завершения обхода заменить номер в верхнем массиве. Так же для вложенного вызова можно передавать не глубину рекурсии, а просто флаг того, что уровень не верхний. Таким образом альтернативный код может быть следующим:

```
function processArray2(&$data, &$num, $isRoot = false){
    $data[] = $num++;
    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        if(!is_array($v)) continue;
        processArray2($data[$k], $num);
    }

    if($isRoot){
        $data[count($data) - 1] = $num;
    }
}

$num = -1;
processArray2($arrayGroup, $num, true);
```

Comment: Работает как надо, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

исходя из вышеперечисленных примеров я понял что вам необходимо вести некий счетчик, и этот счетчик будет увеличиваться если мы натыкаемся на элемент массива, в не зависимости от глубины вложенности. Если я вас неправильно понял - то уточните вопрос, а если правильно - то я бы сделал так

```
    interface ICountToArray{
        public function clearCounter();
        public function getArray($arr);
    }
    /*
    *@property int $counter
    */
    class CountToArray{
        protected $counter=0;
        public function clearCounter(){
            $this->counter=0;
        }
        public function getArray(array $arr){
            foreach($arr as $key=>&$value){
                if(is_array($value)) $arr[$key]=$this->getArray( $arr[$key] );
                unset($value,$key);
            }
            $arr[]=$this->counter;
            ++$this->counter;
            return $arr;
        }

    }
    $transform= new CountToArray();
    print_r($transform->getArray($arryGroup));
```

если вы хотите использовать повторно этот код, то необходимо очистить счетчик

```
$transform->clearCounter();
```

а вообще вся проблема была в том, что рекурсия должна была отдавать  родителю уже измененный счетчик, поэтому функцию я не рекомендую использовать

Comment: заметьте, нумерация узлов в вашем решении не соответствует той, что требуется в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!)